# Ansible Playbook Update all packages Error

Tags: ansible

My code is below for my ansible playbook to update all packages is below with the error I receive when I try running it.

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
   - name: upgrade all packages
     yum:
       name: '*'
       state: latest

fatal: [3.82.200.205]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).\r\n", "unreachable": true}
```

When I checked the connection to my host ip I get the all clear:

```
ansible all -m ping --private-key cpsc407a5.pem
3.82.200.205 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

I'm at a loss as to what could be the issue any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am attaching my hosts file so you can see it.

```
# This is the default ansible 'hosts' file.
#
# It should live in /etc/ansible/hosts
#
#   - Comments begin with the '#' character
#   - Blank lines are ignored
#   - Groups of hosts are delimited by [header] elements
#   - You can enter hostnames or ip addresses
#   - A hostname/ip can be a member of multiple groups

# Ex 1: Ungrouped hosts, specify before any group headers.
3.82.200.205
## green.example.com
## blue.example.com
## 192.168.100.1
## 192.168.100.10

# Ex 2: A collection of hosts belonging to the 'webservers' group

##[webservers]

## alpha.example.org
## beta.example.org
## 192.168.1.100
## 192.168.1.110

# If you have multiple hosts following a pattern you can specify
# them like this:

## www[001:006].example.com

# Ex 3: A collection of database servers in the 'dbservers' group

## [dbservers]
##
## db01.intranet.mydomain.net
## db02.intranet.mydomain.net
## 10.25.1.56
## 10.25.1.57

# Here's another example of host ranges, this time there are no
# leading 0s:

## db-[99:101]-node.example.com
```